# What is the best way to resume a crashed copy using Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, file-transfer

I started to copy about 1TB of files, but `explorer.exe` crashed 80% of the way through.  I cannot simply restart it as some of the files had the same name and I chose the `rename all` option.  I do not want to end up with another copy of these files; how do I resolve this?
I know the last file that it copied.

Comment: You cannot resume the transfer.  You will have to restart it

Comment: copy with skip duplicate enabled?

Comment: Can I find the order in which explorer would have copied the files or does that change?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Windows Explorer does not have a mechanism for recovering where you left off.

Whilst it doesn't help you now, I would highly recommend taking a look at Robocopy that is included in Windows, or, [TeraCopy](https://www.codesector.com/teracopy) for a free graphical tool.

I personally use Windows Explorer every day, but, when I have to transfer over high latency/low bandwidth links, I usually use Robocopy from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

A program providing for synchronizing of files will do as you require. I've used [Allway Sync](https://allwaysync.com/) for this purpose, as it will recognize previously created files and allow you to ignore them during the transfer. It's a free program with restrictions. If the quantity of files to be copied exceed the restriction, it may be necessary to purchase the program.

There may be other free sync-type programs of which I am unaware without restrictions to impact your objective.